# DataBinding not working when i Upgrade Android Studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, gradle

When I update android studio I have an error about `dataBinding`:

> Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder

this is my `build gradle app`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
     'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.theodhor.retrofit2"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
    exclude module: "httpclient"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta2'
}
```

I get this error:

> Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder Open File
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file '/Users/marco/Downloads/Retrofit-master/app/build.gradle' line: 1 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED Total time: 0.686 secs

I don't know why I have this problem.
Who can help me?

Thanks everybody!!!

Comment: Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder
<a href="openFile:/Users/marco/Downloads/Retrofit-master/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/marco/Downloads/Retrofit-master/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.686 secs